# Nested callbacks future / present

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to figure out how to nest callbacks in a certain way.

```
var alpha = function(callback){
    var x = 5;
    if(x > 2){
        callback();
    }else if(x = 10){
        callback();
    }else{
        future();
    }
};

var beta = function(callback){
    var x = 5;
    if(x > 10){
        callback();
    }
}

alpha(function(){
    beta(function(){
      // also run future();
    }); 
});
```

Let's say I wanted `future()` and beta's `callback()` to be the same thing or at least run the same code inside both. how would I make that happen? Please ignore my rudimentary `>` example.

I'm trying to make my code drier. Lets just say that beta runs multiple times within `alpha()` but the `future()` function is already caught up with beta's callback.

**Update**

I want to shy away from being redundant like this.

```
var alpha = function(callback){
    var x = 5;
    if(x > 2){
        //---       
        var x = 5;
        if(x > 10){
            callback();
        }
        //---
    }else if(x = 10){
        //---
        var x = 5;
        if(x > 10){
            callback();
        }
        //---
    }else{
        callback();
    }
};
```

Comment: Just to clarify, did you mean to use equality operators (`==`) instead of assignment (`=`) in your `if` clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept 2 callback functions in your code, also you can define named function (or variable) and use it in beta callback

```
var alpha = function(callback, callback2){
    var x = 5;
    if(x > 2){
        callback();
    }else if(x = 10){
        callback();
    }else{
        callback2();
    }
};

var beta = function(callback){
    var x = 5;
    if(x > 10){
        callback();
    }
}

alpha(function(){
        beta(function(){
           future();
        }); 
    }, function future(){
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if I do, your problem is that you want to invoke a certain behavior within both of your callbacks. To do that, you could simply pass that behavior into the outer callback and then down to your inner callbacks as additional parameters:

```
var alpha = function(future, callback) {
    [...]
    else if(x == 10) {
        callback(future); // Where callback would be beta
    } else {
        future();
    }
}

alpha(future, function(future) {
    beta(function() {
        future();
    });
}
```